# Groovy gpath not working when used with prefixed xml tags

Tags: groovy, gpath

I am having some namespace issues with gpath.

```
String record = '''
    <u:record>
        <u:controlfield tag="001">017003167</u:controlfield>
        <u:datafield ind2="" ind1="" tag="Tag_1234">
            <u:subfield code="a">Peter</u:subfield>
            <u:subfield code="b">10</u:subfield>
        </u:datafield>  
        <u:datafield ind2="" ind1="" tag="Tag_1234">
            <u:subfield code="a">Simon</u:subfield>
            <u:subfield code="b">20</u:subfield>
        </u:datafield>  
        <u:datafield ind2="" ind1="" tag="Tag_20">
            <u:subfield code="a">Simon</u:subfield>
            <u:subfield code="b">20</u:subfield>
        </u:datafield>          
    </u:record>
    '''

GPathResult studentRecord = new XmlSlurper(false, false).parseText(record)
GPathResult filteredRecord = studentRecord.datafield.findAll { it.'@tag' == 'Tag_1234' } 

println "filteredRecord: ${filteredRecord}\n"
println "filteredRecord size is ${filteredRecord.size()}\n"
```

The output is 0. Not sure why it is. If I remove the xml prefix "u:" the gpath works fine. Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: what is 'recordWithPrefixXml' ?

Comment: Its a typo - I have corrected the xml now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
def studentRecord = new XmlSlurper(false, false).parseText(record)
def filteredRecord = studentRecord.'u:datafield'.findAll { it.'@tag' == 'Tag_1234' }
```